How to properly mock updateOne mongoose method in Nest.js using Jest
I want to mock the updateOne method in a Nest.js application using the Jest test library.
I have a service method
public async update(
        newDto: UpdateUserFieldsDTO,
        userName: string,
    ): Promise<UserDocument> {
        const updatedUser = await this.findUserByUserName(userName);

        await this.userModel.updateOne({ userName }, { $set: { ...newDto } });
        return updatedUser;
    }

In it I call another class method to find the user, here is its code
public async findUserByUserName(
        userName: string,
    ): Promise<UserDocument | null> {
        return await this.userModel.findOne({ userName, deletedAt: null });
    }

I wrote tests for the methods and this is what I got:
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";

import { User, UserRole } from "./models/user.model";
import { getModelToken } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth.service";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { CreateUserDTO } from "./dto/createUser.dto";
import { UpdateUserFieldsDTO } from "./dto/updateUser.dto";

const mockUser: CreateUserDTO = {
    email: "string@gmail.com",
    firstName: "str",
    lastName: "str",
    password: "str",
    userName: "userName",
};

const mockUserObject = {
    _id: "12345",
    email: mockUser.email,
    firstName: mockUser.firstName,
    lastName: mockUser.lastName,
    password: mockUser.password,
    userName: mockUser.userName,
    role: UserRole.USER,
    salt: "salt",
    rating: 0,
    lastVoteAt: null,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date(),
    deletedAt: null,
};

class MockedMongoModel {
    constructor(private user: CreateUserDTO) {}

    static readonly findOne = jest.fn(
        async (query: { userName?: string; _id?: string; email?: string }) => {
            if (query._id) {
                return query._id === mockUserObject._id ? mockUserObject : null;
            } else if (query.email)
                return query.email === mockUserObject.email
                    ? mockUserObject
                    : null;
            return query.userName === mockUser.userName ? mockUserObject : null;
        },
    );
    static readonly updateOne = jest.fn(
        async (userName: string, newUserData: UpdateUserFieldsDTO) => {
            const user = await this.findOne({ userName });
            if (newUserData.userName) {
                user.userName = newUserData.userName;
                return user;
            }
        },
    );
}

const MockedAuthModel = {
    generateRandomStr: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("randomStr"),
    hashPassword: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("str"),
};

describe("UserService", () => {
    let service: UserService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UserService,
                {
                    provide: getModelToken(User.name),
                    useValue: MockedMongoModel,
                },
                {
                    provide: AuthService,
                    useValue: MockedAuthModel,
                },
                JwtService,
                ConfigService,
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<UserService>(UserService);

        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it("should be defined", () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it.only("should update user's userName", async () => {
        const updatedUser = {
            ...mockUserObject,
            userName: "user",
        };
        const expectedOutput = await service.update(
            { userName: "user" },
            mockUser.userName,
        );

        expect(MockedMongoModel.updateOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(expectedOutput).toEqual(updatedUser);
    });
});

And here, in a mocked method, I call the class method await this.findOne({ userName }) to get the user. After running the tests I see a picture like this
enter image description here
In the error I see that I am expecting a modified user with "userName": "user" but I am getting "userName": "userName", which means that the code
if (newUserData.userName) {
 user.userName = newUserData.userName;
 return user;
}

is not being executed.
Who can tell me what I did wrong? And how can I correct my code so that I still get the changed user and pass this test?

Your function update returns the user found before the actual update. That would explain your test result.
But, i see a deeper problem, that I tried to explain in the answer section. Hope this helps you in your testing endeavor :)

It seems to me that you went a bit too far in this test. It feels like you want to test the behavior of the mongoose functions (that you pretty much tried to replicate in your MockedMongoModel) when actually, the goal of unit testing is to test your code. Specifically, the code in your UserService (functions update and findUserByUserName), and nothing outside of this scope.
Plus, by implementing the mongoose logic, you might not replicate its behavior perfectly, making your test less relevent.
I would suggest you try to use mockResolvedValue instead. That way, you would mock the behavior of Mongoose (because it is not the purpose of this test, and in the unit testing philosophy, you should "trust it". If you want to test Mongoose as well, then it is not unit testing you are looking for, but rather end-to-end testing for example)
// Create a simpler mongo mock
const mongoMock = {
  findOne: jest.fn(),
  updateOne: jest.fn()
}

// Use it in your testing module
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
    UserService,
    {
      provide: getModelToken(User.name),
      useValue: mongoMock,
    },
    ...

// Finally, rewrite your tests to make use of jest mock functions
it("should update user's userName", async () => {
  const updatedUser = { ...mockUserObject, userName: "user" };
  jest.spyOn(mongoMock.findOne).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockUserObject); // <-- You have to mock this result
  jest.spyOn(mongoMock.updateOne).mockResolvedValueOnce(updatedUser); // <-- You have to mock this result

  const result = await service.update(
    { userName: "user" },
    mockUser.userName,
  );

  expect(mongoMock.updateOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(mongoMock.updateOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ userName: 'userName' }, { $set: { userName: 'user' } });
  expect(result).toEqual(updatedUser);
});

That way, you would simply test the logic YOU implemented, and check that it does what it is suppose to do.
EDIT :
...and by doing so, you would see that your code does not actually return the updated user (since your update functions returns the user before the update). The test I suggested should fail. Which in a way, is a good thing: you get to change your code such as it does exactly what you want!
